# jQuery: Blur with conditions?

Tags: jquery, blur, autosuggest

I have an auto suggest which is pretty similar to the one facebook use, on my website. Basically, as you are typing, it displays a div below the search bar with some search results. But I am having some problems getting it to disappear when another part of the website is clicked, at first I was using:

```
    $("#searchBar").blur(function(){
        $("#quickResults").hide()
    });
```

and it was working fine, until added onClicks to the results which took the user to the page associated with the result, clicking one of the results seemed to also count as a blur for the searchBar and was hiding it before registering the click. I also tried:

```
    $("#searchBar").blur(function(){
        $(".result").blur(function(){
            $("#quickResults").hide()
        });
    });
```

It doesn't seem to like this though and that is causing the div to not hide.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if anyone was having the same problem as me, but I managed to find a solution.

I was showing the div with an ajax success function, I added this to that success function:

```
var events = $(document).data('events') || null;

if (events == null ||( events !== null && !events.click)) {
    $(document).click(function () {
        $('#quickResults').hide();                  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var isBlurred = false;
 $(".result").blur(function(){
    isBlurred = true;
 }).focus(function(){
    isBlurred = false;
 });
 $("#searchBar").blur(function(){
        if(isBlurred)
            $("#quickResults").hide();
 });
```

Comment: I assume I don't need those line breaks?

Comment: unfortunately this is behaving the same as the second solution I tried in the question.